# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

Tags: python, pyodbc

I wrote a code in python and using that for few days. There was no issue in connecting with SQL database. But today morning it throws an error that

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'"

you can see my codes below.

```
    import tkinter as tk    
    from tkinter import ttk        
    import pyodbc
    import self as self

    mydb = pyodbc.connect( 'Driver={SQL Server};'
                           'Server=IPCLINC5H79Y2;'
                           'Database=master;'
                           'Trusted_Connection=yes;' )'''
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed the `pyodbc` package properly (`$ pip install pyodbc`)?

Comment: run `$ pip list` to see the list of packages installed in your current environment.

Comment: In Pycharm > I changed the interpreter directory. After that, I am able to connect to the database. Thanks guys.